# Rails 3.2.13: API Integration Test with Authorization Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration tests for an API I wrote. The api requires authorization prior to access.

I am using FactoryGirl, with the following factory for my user:

```
factory :user do
    name "John Doe"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person-#{n}@testSuite.com" }
    password "password"
    password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
    api_key "1234567890"
end
```

The authenticate method which is called in my controller's before_filter is:

```
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    @current_user = User.where(api_key: token).first
  end
end
```

And my test is

```
test 'User Index' do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    get '/api/v1/users', authorization: "Token token=\"#{@user.api_key}\""
    assert_response :success
end
```

This test continually fails with a response of 401 being returned.

What is the correct way of setting the authorization token so that I can actually connect to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
test 'User Index' do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    get '/api/v1/users', nil, { "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => "Token token=\"#{@user.api_key}\""
    assert_response :success
end
```

See more about [Get in integration tests here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get).

The key you want to set in your header is called: HTTP_AUTHORIZATION